# Correct way for this Mongo Query

Tags: mongodb

[image]

This is what I have tried for the structure :

```
db.briefing.find(
{
  leg : {
  $elemMatch :  {legidentifier : "2A.1003.30Aug2016.BOG.LHR.A"}
  }
}
)
```

This yeilds no results.Where I'm going wrong ?

Comment: use capital i in 'legIndentifier'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DB legIdentifier is saved as **legIdentifier** but in your query you are giving identifier in lower case **legidentifier**.

MongoDB is case-sensitive.